# Start TeamCity build when artifacts are published

Tags: build, teamcity, artifacts

Let's say I have one TeamCity build configuration depending on artifacts taken from another.
It is possible to publish artifacts while build is in progress in TeamCity.
My question is: is it possible to trigger build when all necessary artifacts are available even if builds that are providing these artifacts are still in progress?

The purpose of this is to speed up builds a little.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity, as far as I know, only has the option to trigger on finish of another build configuration, not after publishing artifacts which as you say you can do while the build is still in progress.

Let me ask you another question:

Since whatever you are doing in the build after the publication of the artifacts didn't of course stop you from publishing the artifacts, can't you extract that part out into another build configuration and then have that part fetch the artifacts from this one? This way you can make whatever build configuration you wanted to trigger as soon as you get the artifacts, trigger, well, as soon as you get the artifacts.